# Doesn't get changed value from hidden field on asp

Tags: asp.net

I have on ASP Web Forms element:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="ArrayCoordinateHiddenValue" runat="server" />
```

In Firebug I search next element:

```
<input id="ContentPlaceHolder_ArrayCoordinateHiddenValue" type="hidden" value="{}" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ArrayCoordinateHiddenValue">
```

In firebug I try edit value, and after press button, which get value from this hidden value. But I see value: "{}" Not, that I edit on FireBug. So it is possible fix? Or which element can I use on this situation?

P.S. When I change value on Firebug, I try simulate as JS change value. On tags HTML (Firebug) I serch ID and change value on field.

Comment: How do you edit value in Firebug? As Html tag or as DOM object?